# Lack of existence of antiderivative for complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have been asked to show that the function $f(z) = \frac{z}{z^2+1}$ does not have an antiderivative on the subset $\{z \in \mathbb{C}: 1 < |z| \}$. However I don't see why this is the case, we can write $\frac{z}{z^2+1} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z+i}+\frac{1}{z-i})$ whose naive antiderivative (using $\ln$) has branch points at $\pm i$ so taking a straight line between these points as our branch cut should allow us to make it continuous and single valued on our region. What am I missing?

I know I am making a mistake somewhere as the residue theorem tells me the integral around a circle of radius 2 has value $2\pi i$ and not $0$ so no antiderivative exists. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: And how would you define the function *on* the branch cut, which happens to bisect the unit disk?

Comment: Do we really need to be able to define our function on the branch cut, considering it is not in our domain?

Comment: Do you know *a straight line* (for the branch cut) that does **not** pass through the domain $\;|z|>1\;$ ? This seems to be what you need in order to get your antiderivative...

Comment: The line $\text{Re}(z) = 0$ for $\text{Im}(z) \in [-1,+1]$?

Comment: @AbdulHadiKhan The line  Re$\,z=0\;$ passes through $\;|z|>1\;$ , otherwise it is **not** a line but rather a line *segment* ...

Comment: Can't the branch cut be a line segment though? I seem to recall the line segment $\text{Im}(z) = 0$ and $\text{Re}(z) \in [-1,1]$ being a valid branch cut for $\log(\frac{z-1}{z+1})$. Apologies for seeming slow, I have just started learning complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a positively oriented circle $\Gamma$ of radius $ > 1$ centred at the origin.

$$ \dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\Gamma \dfrac{z}{z^2+1} dz$$
is the sum of the residues of $z/(z^2+1)$ at $\pm i$, namely $1$.  But
if your function had an antiderivative on that region, the result would have to be $0$.